# Formatting the output of a Tree Map

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, printing, output

I have a TreeMap that looks like the following when printed

```
private Map<Double, Double> map = new TreeMap<Double, Double>();
System.out.println(map);
output:
{1=2.9, 3=5.4, 5=98.4, 4=90.1, 2=87.7}
```

I'm wondering how I can print the map to look something more like

```
1 = 2.9
2 = 87.7
3 = 5.4
4 = 90.1
5 = 98.4
```

Right now all I am able to do is do `System.out.println(map);` and get the output that is shown above.

Comment: If you @Override the `toString()` method, you can make it print as anything you like.  Just make your own "PrettyTreeMap" or something with the output you want to see.

Comment: Hint: `map.keySet()` returns the keys, and the set can be iterated in order. All you have to do is to write the loop for printing.

Comment: @laune Better hint, map.entrySet() returns the keys and values so you don't have to use the for (key : map) { map.get(key); } anti-pattern :-).

Comment: @bkail My approach requires only one method call per entry :-)

Comment: Why don't you create a loop which returns the key in order with `map.get(key)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the entries yourself:

```
for (Map.Entry<Double, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Or you can use lambda if you're using Java 8:

```
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " = " + e.getValue()));
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " = " + v));
```

Comment: I think you can omit the stream().

Comment: Actually, I can just use Map.forEach directly.  I clearly had streams on my mind when I wrote the answer :-).

Answer (score 1):

```
Set treeSet = tmap.entrySet();
Iterator iterator = treeSet.iterator();

 while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry integer = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
     System.out.print(integer.getKey() + ": ");
     System.out.println(integer.getValue());
 }
```

Use Java's `Set` and `Iterator`. Make sure you include the following imports:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
```